# Have any big events happened during DST changeover?

Tags: contemporary-history

The alt-text for the XKCD comic [published on 2017-08-30](https://xkcd.com/1883/) notes:

> Someday, some big historical event will happen during the DST changeover, and all the tick-tock articles chronicling how it unfolded will have to include a really annoying explanation next to their timelines.

here, Randall Munroe refers to minute-by-minute — or even second-by-second — timelines / reconstructions that one can find in newspapers or on websites, such as Wikipedia.

Have there been any big events that happened during DST changeover?  By big event, I mean any event big enough such that it was covered with a detailed timeline (at least down to the minute) in major news media.

Comment: I think minimizing such possibility is the main reason that DST changeovers happen in Sunday after midnight

Comment: Nearly all such logging actually occurs on UTC, and the values are translated for local use - So it would be a non-problem.  Either keep the slides in UTC, or include a footnote explaining why 12:30 occurs twice.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace Authorities (or their software) may log in UTC, but legal time is local time (such as for day changeovers) and certainly the press doesn't communicate in UTC, in particular not in places like California or Australia.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding official use, consider how births during the DST change are recorded.  Germany uses "A" and "B", as in 2A o'clock and 2B o'clock. I would expect that professional news organizations would use the standard.